# how to use Stack View of object library in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uistackview

I recently installed **Xcode 7 beta** and found something
 *new* in object library like

**Horizontal stack view and Vertical stack view**.

> When i put some controls inside it, stackview seems to be resizable
>   according to the control size. When i present more controls the stack
>   seems to be adjust automatically as of the stack view.
>   Either
>   adjusting horizontally or vertically?

Is it derived from some other mobile platform

Comment: From Apple's "What's new in Xcode 7" : `Stack views make it easier to layout your views by adding all the necessary constraints automatically. Use stack views to naturally group collections of views so they behave consistently together, and then react as a group to the surrounding UI.`
Also read the docs :)

Comment: i have read doc and i know definition please can u provide me practical suggestion

Comment: Ah, well, there was nothing about practical suggestions in your question :) I can't help you with them, as I haven't yet played with it.

Comment: anyway thank to you, too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*A major advantage of using `UIStackView` is it uses Auto Layout to position and size its arranged `UIViews`. Therefore you dont need to worry about positioning UIViews in a `UIStackView`.For a horizontal stack, this means the first arranged view’s leading edge is pinned to the stack’s leading edge, and the last arranged view’s trailing edge is pinned to the stack’s trailing edge. You can try by inserting two or more controls to a horizontal stack view,how they align horizontally w.r.t each other.*

> The UIStackView class provides a streamlined interface for laying out
>   a collection of views in either a column or a row. Stack views let you
>   leverage the power of Auto Layout, creating user interfaces that can
>   dynamically adapt to the device’s orientation, screen size, and any
>   changes in the available space. The stack view manages the layout of
>   all the views in its arrangedSubviews property. These views are
>   arranged along the stack view’s axis, based on their order in the
>   arrangedSubviews array. The exact layout varies depending on the stack
>   view’s axis, distribution, alignment, spacing, and other properties.

**For how to use**

Here is a detail tutorial from raywenderlich site:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views

**For More,Please have a look at** https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/index.html